# Can you use the particle も after adjective+の?

Tags: grammar, particles

I am trying to say,

> They are usually smartphone games, but there are also pc and console games.

My attempt is this:

> たいていスマホのゲームですが、パソコンのもコンソールのもあります。

I know you can use の alone and ommit the noun when it is obvious, but I'm not sure if it is clear in this sentence and if the use of も next to it is correct.

Comment: My translation attempt is: スマホ用ゲームが中心ですが、PC（パソコン）やゲーム機用のものもあります。It'd be better to provide more context to the original English sentence. You may clarify what the "they" really means so as to elicit more relevant answers. On your translation, it is kind of a bit awkward and unnatural. たいていスマホのゲームですが makes no sense because the subject is unclear, while the two のもs do not fit here; instead of them, it is better to use のものも--for example, パソコンのものも.

Comment: I don’t find OP’s sentence unnatural at all.